# session timeout in asp.net mvc when refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I am running an ASP.NET 4.0 application and published it using plesk control panel.I have done the following.

1.i set session timeout in web.config file as:

```
<sessionState timeout="20000"/>
```

2. I handled session variable in login controller like this:

`Session["userId"] = lUser.userId;
Session["role"] = lUser.userType;`

into other controller, the code is like below:

```
if (Session["role"] == null)
{
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
}
 else if (Session["role"].ToString() == "Admin" || Session["role"].ToString() == "Super Admin")
{
    return View();
}
```

this code is ok in my local server but when published into real server using plesk control panel, it also ok for first time. but when i click the same menu second time it redirects to login page.

Comment: You can try with InProc mode i.e `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20000" cookieless="false"  />`

Comment: I would use Break points and step through to see what your session variable are and where the redirect happens.

Comment: @DaniDev you can't use break point and debug because problem occurs on real server

Comment: @akashkc thanks brother, InProc mode does not work but StateServer mode is working now

Comment: Great!!! StateServer stores session in separate asp.net process which run as windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of SessionState mode="InProc" use SessionState Mode="StateServer", but you'll need to make sure the server where you're hsoting the application has the StateServer active.

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" timeout="20000" cookieless="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["init"] = 0;
}
```

to global.asax

Comment: i have tried with this code but now it redirects me first time